# mvn spring-boot:run build failure

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

When i try to run `mvn spring-boot:run` to launch this project that has worked for others in the past I'm met with this error after the build fails:
[terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JIP7.png)

Would love help from someone who has encountered this before. Error reads:

> failed to execute goal
> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.4.RELEASE:run
> (default-cli) on project resource-profile-repo: Application finished
> with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]

Comment: you should do as maven instructs you: run the command with a "-e" switch so you can see an exception stacktrace. MIght give you more insight.

Comment: Try `mvn org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:run`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help! Turns out I didn't have the proper log in information in my .env for the Database so it was failing the build. User error